# How do I add a method to a button I made programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm working with a pre-existing xcode project for an iPhone app that retrieves flickr pictures. I want to add a favorite button so that a user can add a photo to an array of favorites, but I'm stumped because I've never made UI objects programmatically before.

Here is the code for my button, but how would I add a method do it? Also, where would this method definition go?

```
// Create favorites button
UIButton *favButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
favButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 50, 100, 50);
[favButton setTitle:@"Favorite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

favButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[favButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[favButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[favButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:favButton];
```

Is the addTarget method the way to add a method? Because whenever I click the button, it sends me back to xcode and shows me the main.m file and highlights this line of code:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Sorry, I'm totally new to this. The project has the following files:
    JSONFlickrAppDelegate.h
    JSONFlickrAppDelege.m
    JSONFlickrViewController.h
    JSONFlickrViewController.m
    ZoomedImageView.h
    ZoomedImageView.m

Here is the xcode project that I am working off of:
http://compsci.cis.uncw.edu/~pattersone/courses/275/resources/JSONFlickrPart3.zip

Comment: Have you created the `playAction:` method? Can we see that code. Is it in the same file you're working in? (It should be since the target is `self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the method that adds the method:

```
[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The method, however, that will be called is `playAction:`. Whatever is located after addTarget is simply the *object* that will *call* the method, in the case of self, it is the object where this button is being created that it rests inside.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are some confusions with how you need to add a target to a method.

> **Is the addTarget method the way to add a method?**

Yes, you are correct. `addTarget` method is the way to add a method associated with the button and the method definition should be written on the class which is mentioned as `addTarget` param(In this case `self`, which is an object of current class).

When you use this line,

```
[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It means that you are adding a method named `playAction:` to button which should be executed in target `self` on the event of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` i.e, when an event occurs as user taps inside the button. So the action `playAction` should be inside the class which is represented by the object `self` i.e, the class in which you have written the above `[favButton addTarget:...` line. You can add any number of targets to this same button using similar `addTarget` lines.

> **but how would I add a method do it? Also, where would this method
>   definition go?**

In this scenario, you need to define the method `playAction:` in the same class since you added target as `self`. This can be changed to any object of any class and the method can be written in that class.

for eg:-

```
- (void)playAction:(id)button {
  //write the required code here, button is same as the favbutton which is written above.
}
```

> **Because whenever I click the button, it sends me back to xcode and shows me the main.m
>   file and highlights this line of code:**

The reason why it is going back to xcode and shows the `main.m` is because it is a crashing since you haven't provided any `playAction:` method in your class. Since it cannot find any such method in the target `self`, it will crash and sometimes it just point to the `main.m` class.

You can also add target as follows,

```
[favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//notice that it is 'playAction' and not 'playAction:' with a colon at the end.
```

In this case your method will look like,

```
- (void)playAction {
  //write the required code here
}
```

These are just different ways to do this.

For more details, [please check this apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a)